# Not been able to enter into next page

Tags: android, account

When I m clicking in create account ..then it got stuck and buffered on the same page. And also the data is not saved in firebase's real-time database.

[image]

**RegisterActivity.java**

package com.example.ecom;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button CreateAccountButton;

private EditText InputName,InputPhoneNumber,InputPassword;

private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

private DataSnapshot dataSnapshot;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    CreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn);

    InputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_username_input);

    InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_phone_number_input);

    InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password_input);

    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

    CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            CreateAccount();

        }

    });

}

private void CreateAccount() {

    String name = InputName.getText().toString();

    String phone = InputPassword.getText().toString();

    String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "please write your name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "please write phone number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

        Toast.makeText(this, "please write your password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

else

{

```
        loadingBar.setTitle("Create Account");

        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, While we are checking the credentials.");

        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        loadingBar.show();

        ValidatePhoneNumber(name, phone, password);

    }

}

private void ValidatePhoneNumber(String name, String phone, String password) {
    final DatabaseReference RootRef;

    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override

        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phone).exists())){

                HashMap<String, Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();

                userdataMap.put("phone",phone);

                userdataMap.put("password",password);

                userdataMap.put("name",name);

                RootRef.child("Users").child(phone).updateChildren(userdataMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
```

{

```
                            @Override

                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)

                            {

                                if (task.isSuccessful())

                                {
```

Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Congratulations, your account has been created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
loadingBar.dismiss();

```
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);

                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }

                                else

                                {

                                    loadingBar.dismiss();

                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Network Error: please try again after some time...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                            }

                        });

            }

            else

            {

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "This "+ phone +"already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                loadingBar.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "please try again using another phone number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

        @Override

        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {


        }

    });

}
```

}

Comment: Are you using Real time database to save your data ? if yes then you need to check wether you chose Europe or Central ameican as location of your server , if you are using Europe servers you need to provide database url in your instance

Comment: @Taki Yes I m using a Real-Time database....and I m using American central as the location.

Comment: I guess you need to debug your code by putting breaking points to see where the code stops executing and get to know the issue

Comment: then from which file do I have to start debugging...

Comment: starting from button click and goes on

Comment: @Taki same buffering continues...

Comment: I guess you did not properly debug your code , debugging helps in identifying where could be the issue , you have to track your code through the breakpoints and see if something is null or whatever could be the issue

Comment: @Taki then in which file I  have to debug.

Comment: From start of registration after typing email and password

Comment: @Taki not working...still buffering on both login and register activity....Error is showing "The activity must be exported or contain an intent filter"

Comment: regarding error , go to your manifest file and add exporte="true" to your activity

Comment: @Taki its already added true in MainActivity